# Favicon location in Angular2 template project

Tags: asp.net, angular, webpack, asp.net-core

So I'm new to Angular and Webpack and I've followed this blog for setting up an Angular2 project in Visual Studio: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/ which uses the ASP.NET Core template pack created by Mads Kristensen (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack)

I can't figure out where I need to be putting my favicon (or any images for that matter) so that they get distributed by Webpack.

Should the favicon.ico be getting copied to the wwwroot folder?

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>The Matter Of Faith</title>
        <base href="/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='@Url.Content("~/favicon.ico")' />
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Webpack config:

```
var sharedConfig = {
    resolve: { extensions: [ '', '.js', '.ts' ] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string!css' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$/, loader: 'url', query: { limit: 25000 } }
        ]
    }
};
```

File structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes the favicon needs to be in the web root - I recently discovered this excellent free tool to generate multiple favicons for multiple devices, with the relevant HTML too. The HTML generated for you also explains where to put the icon files.

Give it a try at http://realfavicongenerator.net